# tinyMce bind focusin/focusout events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, focus, tinymce

i am trying like this:

```
setup : function(ed, evt) {
            ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
                tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed.getDoc(), 'focus', function(e) {
                    // Do something when the editor window is blured.
                    alert('focus!!!');
                });
            });
            ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
                tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed.getDoc(), 'blur', function(e) {
                    // Do something when the editor window is blured.
                    alert('blur!!!');
                });
            });
        }
```

but when i focus the textarea i get many alerts saing focus, next blur, next focus,  ... in a loop

what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the right appearance . When you get your `alert("focus!!!")`

you blur the textarea to close the alert. Then you'll get the `alert("blur!!!")`.

After closing this you will get your focus back to the textarea. And the loop continue.

The right way would be not to use alerts for telling your `focus` and `blur`.

Comment: correct! tried with conosole.log instead and i can see what you mean, thanks!